# Is there any javascript client for apache kafka-storm

Tags: javascript, websocket, apache-kafka, apache-storm, amqp

I want to build a real time streaming processing system. I thought of using apache kafka and storm . I got producer and consumer samples written in java ,nodejs etc but I want the similar library for javascript which publish and subscribe events to and from kafka-storm.

Comment: basically I need some client written purely in javascript.

Comment: What's wrong with the nodejs library?

Comment: I need some client side library so that I could publish subscribe from the browser. I don't want to use http for that.

Comment: Could you use something like webpack to bundle the node package for the browser?